# Are the Word2Vec encoded embeddings available online?

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language-processing, word-embedding, word2vec, embeddings

I am trying to do an NLP project and was wondering if there is anywhere online where the Word2Vec embeddings are stored (the actual n-dimmensional vectors).
I want to search up a word and see what its encoding is. I have tried looking but couldn't find anything.
Thank you

Comment: Hello. Are you looking for a tool? If yes, this question is off-topic here. You may want to ask your question here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Hi, not necessarily software, I would just imagine that maybe some websites allows you to search the embedding of a given word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gensim library for Python provides both a convenient way of manipulating Word2Vec embeddings, but also downloadable [data sets and pretrained models](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim-data). That last part is what you're looking for. Wikipedia2Vec also has [multilingual embeddings](https://wikipedia2vec.github.io/wikipedia2vec/pretrained/). Then [this guy](https://github.com/Kyubyong/wordvectors) (whom I've never heard of) has an assortement of languages I haven't seen other places. There's another 44 models hosted by the [European NLPL](http://vectors.nlpl.eu/repository/#). You can also [search Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets?search=word2vec), but a lot of this looks like training data, models I've already linked, or just cruft.